# loop through all the sheets of an excel file and apply a function to each sheet and return the file with all the modified sheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to iterate through each sheet of an Excel file, fill all the nan values with zero (fillna(0), and apply a function to each sheet. Then save the Excel sheets with the function applied on each sheet to an Excel file with separate sheets (like the original file - I mean I do not want to concatenate the sheets). I only get the first sheet save and not the rest of the sheets. any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

def my_fun(g)

    # Find the row where 'Normalized Area' is equal to 1
    g["Normalized Area"] = pd.to_numeric(g["Normalized Area"], errors='coerce')
    row_with_1 = g[g["Normalized Area"] == 1]

    print(row_with_1.shape)
    # Get the corresponding 'E' value
    e_value = row_with_1.iloc[0]["Metabolite Conc Theory"]

    # Multiply 'D' by the 'E' value and store the result in column 'F'

    g["Semi Quantitative Conc"] = g["Normalized Area"] * e_value

    return g
#read file with multiple sheets in a dict format
dfs = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\zj\Ad relative measurements to semi-quantitative.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

#loop through sheets , for each sheet as a df fill nan values with 0 and apply a function (g) AND save all sheets separately in a excel file 
for df in dfs.values():
    df.fillna(0)

    df = df.groupby("Metabolite" , group_keys=False).apply(my_fun)
    df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\zj\Ad relative measurements to semi-quantitative.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

your issue is that you're not creating a new excel writer object to write too, I would suggest writing a new file so you don't over-write your old one.

something like this *should* work but I've not tested it.

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\zj\Ad relative measurements to semi-quantitative.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

#loop through sheets , for each sheet as a df fill nan values with 0 and apply a function (g) AND save all sheets separately in a excel file 

with pd.ExcelWriter(
    r"C:\Users\zj\Ad relative measurements to semi-quantitative.xlsx",
    engine="xlsxwriter",
) as writer:

    for name, sheet in dfs.items():
        sheet = sheet.fillna()
        sheet = sheet.groupby("Metabolite", group_keys=False).apply(my_fun)
        sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
```

Comment: From within the `for` loop, `sheet` is a dataframe, it can't be dictionary keys. I'd reckon that we'd do `for name, sheet in dfs.items():`.

Comment: @Umar.H, I used your code but it still works only on the first page. So, it returns an Excel sheet with only one page and the previous pages are gone because it overwrites the original file with the new Excel sheet.

Comment: @QuangHoang that's what I get for answering via my phone :D